# how to get actual height of an image which its width is inherit and height is set to auto?

Tags: jquery, image, height

hello sorry for asking dumb question:/
 I need to know the height of an image which its width is set to 100%;
 and please consider ,not original height of image,but the height which actually is seen in client side!
PS. I permanently get original height when use this:

$('#myImage').height();
 please help:(

thank a lot

Comment: `$('#myImage').css('height')`

Comment: my original image height is 870px , but height is set to auto,so in smaller window height should be smaller,but is methods always returns 870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to get the correct height with `.height()` or `.css('height')` it might be that the browser returns the height before the image has fully loaded.

Try using the `.load()` function:

```
$('#myImage').load(function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: ,thank you so much it worked :) just one thing more: is there any way to get this value each time window re-sized ? i mean somehow _real-time_ i tried this but didn't work: `$(window).resize(function(){$('#myImage').load(function(){
    var h = $(this).height();
}); });`